# XUbuntu 12.04 GRUB recovery after separate Windows 7 install

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, mbr, grubrescue

I have a RAID drive: /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed with root Linux partition at: /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed7.

I've installed Windows 7 on the separate partition so it rewritten the boot loader.

Now i'm trying to reinstall GRUB2 to the MBR using XUbuntu's LiveCD.

I'm doing:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed7 /mnt

sudo grub-install --recheck --root-directory=/mnt /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed7.  Check your device.map.
Auto-detection of a filesystem of /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed7 failed.
Try with --recheck.
If the problem persists please report this together with the output of "/usr/sbin/grub-probe --device-map="/mnt/boot/grub/device.map" --target=fs -v /mnt/boot/grub" to <bug-grub@gnu.org>
```

Here's the output of requested command:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe --device-map="/mnt/boot/grub/device.map" --target=fs -v /mnt/boot/grub

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: cannot open `/mnt/boot/grub/device.map'.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: changing current directory to /dev/mapper.
deps dm_task creation failed
deps dm_task creation failed
deps dm_task creation failed
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: no mapping exists for `/dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed7'.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/mapper/isw_bjeeefeied_Lightspeed7.  Check your device.map.
```

- "/boot" is not a separate filesystem in my case.

How can i properly reinstall GRUB2 to the MBR so i can boot my XUbuntu desktop as well as Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

The top answer at this link worked like a charm for me. I just installed Windows 8 onto the same machine as my Xubuntu so it overwrote the grub loader and used the Windows bootloader. This switched it back to using the grub loader. Hope it helps!

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)